# number of records in a table in SQL

Tags: sql

How to write a select statement that gets the total number of records in a table.

```
Criteria

Data.Reconciled = 0
Data.Filled = 1
Data.Sub_Needed = 1
Data.Deleted = 0
```

Must be able to provide a date range that would only look at jobs that have a contract_date in the date range provided.

Data must be grouped by Disk Name.

ISPN Name must be displayed for each line next to the Disk Name.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your schema, and which RDBMS?

Comment: Is this homework?  Does the homework have the structure of the tables, etc?

Comment: no its not homework. i am just practicing my skill .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT info.ISD, Data.ispnName, Data.diskName, COUNT(*) 
FROM Data, info
WHERE Data.Reconciled = 0 AND
    Data.Filled = 1 AND
    Data.Sub_Needed = 1 AND
    Data.Deleted = 0 AND
    Data.contract_date >= 'START DATE' AND
    Data.contract_date <= 'END DATE'
GROUP BY Data.diskName
```

Comment: Thanks, one last thing. These following are not in the same table,  info.ISD Name must be displayed for each line next to the info.Disk Name.

Comment: how can i use join? is same qurey

Comment: If you want to use a join you need a relation between the tables(some data in common to join it).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from Data where Data.Reconciled = 0 and Data.Filled = 1 and Data.Sub_Needed = 1 and Data.Deleted = 0 and Data.contract_date >= '1-1-2011' and Data.contract_date <= '12-31-2010' group by data.diskname
```

the actual structure of your tables would help fill in the blanks.

Comment: select count(*) from  Data
where Data.Reconciled = 0 and Data.Filled = 1 
 AND Data.Sub_Needed = 1 and Data.Deleted = 0   NOTE* This part i cant do (Must be able to provide a date range that would only look at jobs that have a contract_date in the date range provided.

Data must be grouped by Disk Name.

ISPN Name must be displayed for each line next to the Disk Name.)